# Paypal Merchant account for multiple websites

Tags: paypal, return, merchant-account

My client having single paypal merchant account. IPN Notify Url sets to one website. But we are using same account for two websites. The problem is after payment process completed, paypal redirects to IPN Notify Url. But, I want to redirect to My website. Means Paypal redirects to their respected websites without considering the IPN. Is it possible? If Yes please suggest me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I am in the middle of getting the exact same thing setup currently. PayPal calls this a "Parent/Child Account". Basically what happens is the following:

- You setup 1 main account on PayPal which has your bank information stored
- You setup a secondary account (with no bank account, however both are business accounts)

Call PayPal and inform them you want the secondary account linked to the main PayPal account so that they both share the same financial information (Parent/Child Accounts). They will make the change in their system so that both of the PayPal accounts look like 100% separate businesses with no information leaking from one to the other, it's as if neither of the two checkout pages know each other.

On the back-end, what happens is you get paid on the 2nd account and the money is transferred to the main account at the end of the day, which you can then transfer to your bank account.

I believe this is a U.S. only feature, however feel free to call them and ask for help in getting it setup. If they give you the run-around, telling you that this is impossible, tell them you need to speak to someone else. I was on the phone with 7, yes SEVEN, different people in one call, and I had to call back and went through 4, yes FOUR, for a total of ELEVEN people, before I finally got to the one person who set it up like I wanted it setup. It is possible. Be persistent and don't let them tell you it isn't (unless their reasoning is you not being in the US).

Good luck!